# Java regExp get sub-sting before last quote

Tags: java, regex

I have a sting:

```
String text = "\"Alaska \"adaa\" asdas\" at [2013-10-298 13:36.062];";
```

I need to get substing

```
//"Alaska "adaa" asdas"
String text = "\"Alaska \"adaa\" asdas\"";
```

How to?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use [`lastIndexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29)?

```
text = text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf("\"") + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
text.replace("\"[^\"]*$", "\"")
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be replacing everything after the last quote with an empty string:

```
test = test.replaceAll("(?<=\")[^\"]*$", "");
//                      ^^^^^^^ ^^^  ^
//                         |     |   |
// Preceded by a quote ----+     |   |
// Does not contain a quote -----+   |
// Goes all the way to the end ------+
```

Comment: yep, this works. thanks. is a ability not to replace, but substring with regexp? coz i'll need that line in future

Comment: @wingsofovnia One way would be storing it into a different `String` - say, `String dropTail = test.replaceAll(...)`. This would leave the original `test` intact.

Comment: @dasblinkednlight yep, but too plain and simple heh) thanks, anyway)